# LMDB error on Ubuntu

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb, caffe2

I was going through the MNIST tutorial in caffe2 and I ran into the following error:

```
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at db.h:190] db_. Cannot open db: /home/Aakash/caffe2_notebooks/tutorial_data/mnist/mnist-train-nchw-lmdb of type lmdb Error from operator: 
output: "dbreader_/home/Aakash/caffe2_notebooks/tutorial_data/mnist/mnist-train-nchw-lmdb" name: "" type: "CreateDB" arg { name: "db_type" s: "lmdb" } arg { name: "db" s: "/home/Aakash/caffe2_notebooks/tutorial_data/mnist/mnist-train-nchw-lmdb" }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: do you have the lmdb file on your disk? do you have reading permissions for the database?

Comment: The dir has 777 permission.

Comment: is it possible someone else is accessing the lmdb at the same time? is it possible you have other process suspended that was accessing the lmdb?

Comment: No. I am following this tutorial. https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/python/tutorials/MNIST.ipynb

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this the whole day and finally found the solution.

I am using Python's Anaconda distribution and was facing same issue.

Make following changes inside < CAFFE_ROOT >/scripts/build_anaconda.sh:

```
-caffe2_cmake_args+=("-DUSE_LMDB=OFF")
+caffe2_cmake_args+=("-DUSE_LMDB=ON")
```

And then run `./scripts/build_anaconda.sh --install-locally` to build the caffe2 source for anaconda.